# Reorder TableView lists and update data in SQLITE Database

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite, uitableview

I have implemented an iPhone application with **sqlite** as my backend.

In that I have a Table '*PrioritysDatabaseTable**' for Some Priorityin Database..

With **`two columnsPriorityID (Primary key + Auto Increment) & PriorityTitle(VarChar)`**

I retrieve the records in an array from the 'PrioritysDatabaseTable' and displayed in a table view.

In Edit table view i Have 3 features **1.Add new Priority , 2.Delete RPriority, 3.ReOrder Prioritys**.

[image]

**1.add newPriority:** I inserted a PriorityTitle in Text Field and Implemented Insert Method in sqlite DataBase.

**2. deletPriority:** delete By taping on delete button beside the cells, implemented Delete method in sqlite Database.

These two are working fine,

Problem is when **reader the table..**

I can **`reorder in visible but not in data base..`**

I used some logics in update query to reorder database table but these are failed in some scenarios..

Can any one have the proper implementation

Comment: How are your reordering the rows? Alphabetically?

Comment: what are you reordering ..through primary key or roleTitle ...

Comment: You can add order_id in your database table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

Remove all my table data from data base

and re insert from the Array, that retrieve the records in an array from the 'rolesDatabaseTable'

with changed order